# CMake and make looking for libjawt.so file in the wrong place

Tags: java, c++, makefile, cmake, java-native-interface

I have a C++, Java, and CMake project but I am, at the moment, unable to compile it. I encounter the following error.

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/jvm/default/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so', needed by 'build/Ygor'.  Stop.
```

From what I've read online that means the compiler cannot find that file, either it's looking in the wrong place or it doesn't exist. Sure enough, it's in the wrong place. On my computer the libjawt.so file is actually located at `/usr/lib/jvm/default/lib/libjawt.so`. There is no `jre` in `/usr/lib/jvm/default/`.

I would like for the compiler to accurately locate the file it's looking for. Either automatically or by me telling it where it is. However I am at a loss as to how to express this to the compiler. I've tried to add `include_directories("/usr/lib/jvm/default/lib")` to the uppermost CMakeLists.txt file but that changes nothing. I am aware of the `add_library` and `find_library` CMake functions but if they could help me in this situation I don't know how to use them to do that.

Here is the full compiler output.

```
Scanning dependencies of target CommandParser
[  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/CommandParser.dir/CommandParser.cpp.o
[ 14%] Linking CXX static library libCommandParser.a
[ 14%] Built target CommandParser
Scanning dependencies of target Item
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Item.dir/Item.cpp.o
[ 28%] Linking CXX static library libItem.a
[ 28%] Built target Item
Scanning dependencies of target Dependency
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Dependency.dir/dependency.cpp.o
[ 42%] Linking CXX static library libDependency.a
[ 42%] Built target Dependency
Scanning dependencies of target Parser
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Parser.dir/Parser.cpp.o
[ 57%] Linking CXX static library libParser.a
[ 57%] Built target Parser
Scanning dependencies of target Actor
[ 64%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Actor.dir/Actor.cpp.o
[ 71%] Linking CXX static library libActor.a
[ 71%] Built target Actor
Scanning dependencies of target Room
[ 78%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Room.dir/Room.cpp.o
[ 85%] Linking CXX static library libRoom.a
[ 85%] Built target Room
Scanning dependencies of target Ygor
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Ygor.dir/src/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/jvm/default/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so', needed by 'build/Ygor'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:131: CMakeFiles/Ygor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:104: all] Error 2
```

And here is the uppermost CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Ygor)
# Version Numbers
set (Ygor_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (Ygor_VERSION_MINOR 1)
set (Ygor_VERSION "${Ygor_VERSION_MAJOR}.${Ygor_VERSION_MINOR}")
# Output
set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build")

# Include directories
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build")
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/include")
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/include/linux")
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/stanford-corenlp")
include_directories ("/usr/lib/jvm/default/lib")
add_subdirectory (src)
# Find the JNI package
find_package(JNI)
if (JNI_FOUND)
    include_directories("${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()

add_executable (Ygor src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Ygor Parser)
target_link_libraries (Ygor Dependency)
target_link_libraries (Ygor CommandParser)
target_link_libraries (Ygor Actor)
target_link_libraries (Ygor Item)
target_link_libraries (Ygor Room)
if (JNI_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries (Ygor ${JNI_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the line:

```
find_package(JNI)
```

CMake provides [several JNI cache variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindJNI.html#cache-variables) that allow you to specify the location of the associated libraries (if not found or found libraries are not correct). You can run `cmake` from the command line on your project to see a list of the cache variables:

```
cmake -LA
```

This is also easily viewable in the CMake GUI. If the value for the `JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY` variable is incorrect, you can run CMake again, providing an updated value for that variable:

```
cmake -DJAVA_AWT_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/jvm/default/lib/libjawt.so ..
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to also change JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY to look in the correct place. But this seems to have only kicked the can into another brick wall. ld cannot find the java library because it's also looking in the wrong place.
I'm going to try to search for an easy solution but I may have to create many, many symbolic links in the files it is searching. I'm accepting this answer because it answered the question I asked, even if it didn't totally solve my problem.